# mount an old copy of an encrypted home folder

Tags: 18.04, mount, ecryptfs

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and created a copy of the Home partition which included my encrypted home folder. At the time I didn't realize the UUID was also duplicated which I have since fixed. I have read the various instructions about accessing my encrypted home folder and would like to access the version in the copied partition. It's just not clear to me that the scripts provided will let me put that copy where I'd like to. They all seem to want to put it on top of my home folder. Everything I find talks to a previous version of Ubuntu and I am a bit reluctant to try this for fear of scrambling things up. I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
    sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda7 /mnt/sda7  
    sudo mount -t ???? Some-place-of-my-choosing
    *do my thing*
```

Please advise.